# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar un Json en php?

Tags: php, json

tengo el siguiente inconveniente, y es que quiero ordenar un json que obtengo, el Json es el siguiente:

```
[
{
    "i": "878",
    "n": "Alarcon de Chocolate SanTelmo 1/2 Libra",
    "p": "30000",
    "g": "2017/10/pudin-alarcon-de-chocolate-san-telmo.jpg"
},
{
    "i": "880",
    "n": "Ferrero Rocher SanTelmo 1/2 Libra",
    "p": "40000",
    "g": "2017/10/ferrero-rocher-san-telmo-1.jpg"
},
{
    "i": "882",
    "n": "Naranja y Amapola San Telmo 1/2 Libra",
    "p": "30000",
    "g": "2017/10/naranja-y-amapola-santelmo.jpg"
},
{
    "i": "884",
    "n": "Red Velvet SanTelmo 1/2 Libra",
    "p": "35000",
    "g": null
},
{
    "i": "886",
    "n": "Marmolada de Chocolate SanTelmo 1/2 Libra",
    "p": "30000",
    "g": null
},
{
    "i": "888",
    "n": "Ferrero Rocher SanTelmo 1 Libra",
    "p": "70000",
    "g": null
},
{
    "i": "890",
    "n": "Naranja y Amapola SanTelmo 1 Libra",
    "p": "50000",
    "g": null
},
{
    "i": "892",
    "n": "Red Velvet SanTelmo 1 Libra",
    "p": "60000",
    "g": null
},
{
    "i": "893",
    "n": "Marmolada de Chocolate SanTelmo 1 Libra",
    "p": "50000",
    "g": null
}
]
```

Quiero saber cómo ordenarlo en php por la key "p", Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero pasa el json a array, luego ordenar con el [usort de php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), y si el atributo "p" siempre es un entero puedes usar la función comparar:

```
function comparar($a, $b)
{
    if ((int) $a['p'] == (int) $b['p']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ((int) $a['p'] < (int) $b['p']) ? -1 : 1;
}
$array = json_decode($json, true);
usort($array, 'comparar');
```

Answer (score 1):

Puede simplemente usar la función [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.usort.php) y con el ejemplo de la documentación bastaría. En la función si desea ordenar de mayor a menor sería primero el parámetro `$b` y luego `$a` , si desea lo contrario simplemente cambiaría el orden de los parámetros.

Tanto `$a` como `$b` serán arrays, por lo tanto si desearía cambiar por otro indice del array, por ejemplo `i` , bastaría cambiar `["p"]`  por `["i"]`

```
function comparar($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($b["p"], $a["p"]); //mayor a menor
    //return strcmp($a["p"], $b["p"]); //menor a mayor
}

usort($array, "comparar");
```